# JavaScript RegExp concatinating variable

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Trying to replace all a's in the string ignoring the case.

```
str = "All a's will be replaced";
str.replace(/a/gi, 'Aa');
```

As expected, the above line of code produces `Aall Aa's will be replAaced`

But,

```
regExp = new RegExp('/a/gi');
str.replace(regExp, 'Aa');
```

the above line with the use of RegExp pattern produces original string `All a's will be replaced`

How to achieve expected result?

Comment: Because `/` and `/gi` are now part of the pattern, see [how your regex matches the string `/a/gi`](http://jsfiddle.net/cjk1dL42/)

Comment: Also, when using `new RegExp`, you need to pass the flags in the *second* argument, not as part of the string in the first argument.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah. I totally forgot. thanks.